# Storing constants in Storage vs Creating a view function? (Solidity 0.5.17)

Tags: solidity, gas, storage, gas-estimate, solidity-0.5.x

So, which would be gas efficient?

Reading a storage variable in a state-changing function?

OR

Reading from a pure function in a state-changing function?

Example:

```
contract Test {
    uint256 public a = 10;
    
    uint256 public b = 1;
    
    function aPure() public pure returns(uint256) {
        return 10;
    }
    
    function aFunc() public {
        b = a;
    }
    
    function aPureFunc() public {
        b = aPure();
    }
}
```

In the above, will `aFunc()` have lower gas cost or `aPureFunc()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a simple way I used to check the cost is in Remix IDE, with Gas Profiler. And the results were:

`aFunc()`

Transaction cost: 23096

Execution cost: 1824

`aPureFunc()`

Transaction cost: 22265

Execution cost: 993

So, it turns out, reading from the pure function is gas efficient compared to reading from storage if there are no calculations being done.